# How to find matrix of antisymmetrization $\pi_A(g)$ where $g$ is the bilinear form $e^1\otimes e^1-e^1\otimes e^2+3e^2\otimes e^1+2e^2\otimes e^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors, bilinear-form

Basis $M=\{(3,1),(2,1)\}$. I solved that the dual basis
\begin{equation}
M^*=\{e^1,e^2\}=\{(1,-2),(-1,3)\}
\end{equation}

Then I solved that matrix

\begin{equation}
g=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&-5\\-1&10\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}

Now, my notes says that antisymmetrization matrix for purely covariant tensor (which is a bilinear form) is given as

$$\frac{1}{q!}\sum_{\pi \in S_q}\text{sgn}\pi.(e_{\pi(1)},.....,e_{\pi(n)})$$

Here $q$ is 2 (because bilinear form is a (0,2) tensor and since we're in 2 dimensional space, there should be two permutations).

If I understant correctly, my matrix should be equal to

$$\frac{1}{2}\left((e_1,e_2)-(e_2,e_1)\right),$$

I just don't know what these $e_1$ and $e_2$ mean (I suppose they are not meant to be the same as the basis vectors of $M$).

Are $e_1$ and $e_2$ meant to be columns of the matrix $g$?

In that case the matrix of antisymmetrization would be

$$\pi_A(g)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{cc}6&-6\\-11&11\end{array}\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the $e_{\pi(i)}$ are inteded to be the same you computed in the dual basis, but with another meaning. In fact, $(e_2,e_1)$ and $(e_1,e_2)$ are to be intended as a permutation operators on the tensor.

In particular, $(e_1,e_2)$ is the identity operator, whereas $(e_2,e_1)$ swaps the indices as
$$
(e_2,e_1) (e_1\otimes e_1) =e_2 \otimes e_2,\\
(e_2,e_1) (e_1\otimes e_2) =e_2 \otimes e_1,\\\dots
$$
Notice that these operators are linear, and you can compute their effect on the matrix. In fact, $(e_1,e_2)$ does not change the matrix $g$, whereas $(e_2,e_1)$ coincides with the transposition of the matrix.

In your case,
$$
\pi_A(g)=\frac{1}{2}(g-g^T)
$$
that is what is commonly known as the skew(or anti)-symmetric part of $g$.